# How to call the next page in my parse - Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I've tried everything but I can't seem to figure it out how I can call the next page in the parse_category.

I've tried LinkExtractor as I do when I go directly to a catergory page but this didn't work.

```
import scrapy.selector 
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from msh_final.items import CrawlerMshFinalItem


def complete_url(string):
    return "http://www.mediamarkt.be" + string


def get_base_url(url):
    if url != "":
        u = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        return "%s://%s" % (u.scheme, u.netloc)
    else:
        return ""


def encode(str):
    return str.encode('utf8', 'ignore')


class msh_finalSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'msh_final'
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_Telefoon-Navigatie,98952,509451.html?langId=-17']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//ul[@class="infield cf"]//div[@class="infield-wrapper"]/h2/a/@href')
        for item in items:
            link = item.extract()
            yield Request(complete_url(link), callback=self.parse_category)

    def parse_category(self, response):
        items = response.xpath("//ul[@class='products-list']/li/div")
        for item in items:
            msh = CrawlerMshFinalItem()
            msh['item_price'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/div/text())').extract()[0])
            msh['item_name'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//div/h2/a/text())').extract()[0])
            yield msh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inherite your spider from `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider` and use following code:

```
class msh_finalSpider(Spider):
    name = 'msh_final'
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_Telefoon-Navigatie,98952,509451.html?langId=-17']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//ul[@class="infield cf"]//div[@class="infield-wrapper"]/h2/a/@href')
        for item in items:
            link = item.extract()
            yield Request(complete_url(link), callback=self.parse_category)

    def parse_category(self, response):
        items = response.xpath("//ul[@class='products-list']/li/div")
        for item in items:
            msh = CrawlerMshFinalItem()
            msh['item_price'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/div/text())').extract()[0])
            msh['item_name'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//div/h2/a/text())').extract()[0])
            yield msh

        new_link = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination-next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
        yield Request(
            complete_url(new_link),
            callback=self.parse_category
        )
```